# Reading Calendar Event

Tags: xamarin.android

I have added a calendar event in device via my application. Then I try to read the same using my application, it getting successfully. Then I delete event from my device calendar, again I try to read the same event via my application few android devices (ex nokia, vivo etc) shows there is no event exists but in Samsung device (any OS version) it shows the event is there?
Please help.

```
string[] calendarsProjection = { CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Title, CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Dtstart, CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Dtend,
                                         CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.EventLocation,CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.CalendarId,CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.HasAlarm};

        var selection = CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.CalendarId + " = ? AND " + CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Title + " = ? AND " + CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Dtstart + " >= ? AND "
         + CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Dtend + " <= ?";

        var selectionArgs = new string[] { "1", eventTitle, startTimeStamp.ToString(), endTimeStamp.ToString() };

        var cursor = Android.App.Application.Context.ContentResolver.Query(event_uri, calendarsProjection, selection, selectionArgs, null);


            while (cursor.MoveToNext())
            {
                string title = cursor.GetString(0);
                string startTime = cursor.GetString(1);
                string endTime = cursor.GetString(2);
            }
```

Comment: Can you share more of the code?

Comment: @Yserbius Update the code inline, please look into it

Comment: do you mean,when you delete the event in device calendar, on Samsung device still could read the event ?

Comment: Yes. after deleting event from device calendar, then application and read the event, we got there is a event is there

Comment: @Yserbius any idea?